# Can multiple submissions of PHP forms be effectively prevented with sessions without destroying the caching mechanism?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, security, session

Lets say we have a certain endpoint in a Symfony CMS application for receiving form submissions (e.g. of a contact form). This endpoint sends a copy of the contact form contents to the E-Mail entered within the contact form.

As soon as an attacker finds out about how the endpoint works (which is pretty easy) he could just go behind the Captcha after validating it once and use the endpoint directly in order to send thousands of E-Mails using the sender address of the companys' mailserver (server side Captcha validation will help, but it is not a full answer to this question).

Therefore a mechanism is needed in order to prevent attackers from doing this - at least to easily. The first solution which came to my mind was tokens. The problem with tokens is that they do not play very well together with caching, implementing an ajax endpoint for tokens would just require an attacker to fetch a new token from the first endpoint and send it to the other endpoint among with new data.

**So my idea is like this:**

- Create an ajax endpoint which creates a PHP session. It is 
  called via JavaScript everytime a page with a form is opened (so
  there will be a PHP session whenever a form is submitted)
- If the form is submitted and there is no valid session the server
  instantly returns an error after sending the form
- The form ID will be saved within the session. On the server side it
  is validated if the form was sent by this user within e.g. the last
  two  minutes and if yes, form processing is denied.
- The `SessionService` class which does `session_start();` is only included in
  the ajax endpoint for creating sessions as well as in the ajax
  endpoint for form submissions. Therefore normal CMS pages can still be
  cached as `session_start();` is never called.

Is there a serious issue with this kind of implementation or is it a good solution to the problem? If you see a problem how would you solve it instead?

Comment: *"... use the endpoint directly ..."* — *RECORD SCRATCH* Wait a second, the CAPTCHA you implemented is just fronting and is not validated at all by the endpoint that does the actual work? Well, there's your problem. Require a valid CAPTCHA as argument for the *endpoint*, or don't expose that endpoint publicly.

Comment: @deceze Yes you are right. The CAPTCHA is currently not in the backend (serious fail) and I am about to solve it. But the Captcha will not provide a mechanism to limit the number of submissions if you solve the Captcha everytime right? Because then I still would like to know if I can limit to one subscription per two minutes with the solution suggestion provided.

Comment: Well, yes, you can use the API as long as you solve the CAPTCHA each time. That's *usually* already good enough. For rate-limiting, I'd go with something like http://www.fail2ban.org instead of overcomplicating the architecture.

Comment: @deceze Ok I guess this is a good answer 